# HttpGet returns 404 in Mvc core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

```
public class SurveyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var surveys = new List<int>{1};
        return View(Surveys);
    }

    [HttpGet("conditions")]
    public IActionResult GetConditions()
    {
        List<int> Conditions = new List<int{1};
        return View("Conditions",Conditions);
    }
}
```

Now the views are under

`Views/Survey/Index.cshtml`

`Views/Survey/Conditions.cshtml`

The route `Survey/conditions` is returning `404` .

Does anybody has any idea ?

My startup.cs is -

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });   
}
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting?

Comment: @Amy `/survey/conditions`

Comment: I don't use `HttpGet` for routing personally, but doesn't your code make the URL to just `/conditions`? Try `[HttpGet("/survey/conditions")]` for example

Comment: [Indeed, it does.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.httpgetattribute.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_HttpGetAttribute__ctor_System_String_)

Comment: What I understand is it comes from the top controller level . so you want to say that it just boils down to conditions when we use just route ?

Comment: That's what that overload of `HttpGet` does.

Comment: I see . I tried with route attribute also . But it resulted the same .

Comment: So irrespective of if I use `Route` or `HttpGet`. It is boiling down to `/Conditions ` . Is there any reason for it ?

Comment: Are you using the `Route` attribute on the controller?

Comment: No I am not I think that is the one causing the issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute you have on the action:

```
[HttpGet("conditions")]
```

is specifying that you want the URL to be `http://whatever/conditions`. Instead you should use:

```
[HttpGet("/survey/conditions")]
```

If you're looking to control your routing with better granularity, you should use the `Route` attribute instead. For example:

```
[Route("[controller]")] //Set the prefix for subsequent route attributes
public class SurveyController : Controller
{
    [Route("conditions")]
    public IActionResult GetConditions()
    {
        List<int> Conditions = new List<int{1};
        return View("Conditions",Conditions);
    }
}
```

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public class SurveyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var surveys = new List<int>{1};
        return View(Surveys);
    }

    [HttpGet("conditions")]
    [Route("Survey/conditions")]
    public IActionResult GetConditions()
    {
        List<int> Conditions = new List<int{1};
        return View();
    }
}
```

or change the name of function in controller:

```
public class SurveyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var surveys = new List<int>{1};
        return View(Surveys);
    }

    [HttpGet("conditions")]
    public IActionResult conditions()
    {
        List<int> Conditions = new List<int{1};
        return View();
    }
}
```

or write the name of function in browser route in browser:

Route = 'Survey/GetConditions'